# Dojo - Dijit Dialog

Tags: dialog, dojo

Is it possible to load another page into dialog like this:

```
<div id="external" dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="My external dialog"
    href="yahoo.com" style="overflow:auto; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

I am getting an error "Unable to load yahoo.com status:404.

It works if I point to my static page like:

```
<div id="external" dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="My external dialog"
    href="index.jsp" style="overflow:auto; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The href attribute needs to point to a URL on the same domain.
If you want to load content from another domain, you can embed an iframe inside your dialog.

I have created a fiddle to demo this: http://jsfiddle.net/vijayagrawal/3tdSm/1/